# Ошибка при компиляции динамического массива

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    printf("Vvedite kol-vo elementov: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *a = new int[n];
    printf("Vvedite elementi: ");
    for (i > 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        if (a[i] < 0)
        {
            a[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", a[i]);
    delete[]a;
    getch();
}
```

Выдает ошибку в следующих местах:

```
int *a = new int[n];
delete[]a;
```

Comment: В [tag:си] не существует операторов `new` `delete`. Есть `malloc/calloc`, `free`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В си не существует операторов `new` `delete`. Есть `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`, `free`.

Ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    printf("Vvedite kol-vo elementov: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    printf("Vvedite elementi: ");
    for (i > 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        if (a[i] < 0)
        {
            a[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", a[i]);
    free(a);
    getch();
}
```